# Create Screens Using Bash Shell Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to create screens and run python script using bash. The script works fine in local. But, when I run the same script in the server, **screens are getting created but python script is not executing in some screens**. Any issues with the code?

```
   #!/bin/bash
   inc=9
   end=$(expr "$2" + "$inc")

   for i in $(seq -w "$2" $end)
   do
      screen -dmS "$1$i" bash
      screen -r "$1$i" -p 0 -X exec python test.py
   done
```

And I execute as **sh auto_start.sh pyt 1**

Comment: You don't need `expr`: `end=$(( $2 + $inc ))` You also don't really need `end`: `for ((i=$2; i<=$2 + $inc; i++)); do`.

Comment: yeah, but will this be an issue?

Comment: while not ideal, you can eliminate a whole class of error by specifying full paths to `python` and to your `.py` files. Good luck.